# Call 32-bit or 64-bit program from bootloader

Tags: c, assembly, bootloader

There seems to be quite a lot of identical information on the Internet about writing the following 3 bootloaders:

1. Infinite loop `jmp $`
2. Print a single character
3. Print "Hello World".

This is fantastic, and I've gone through these 3 variations with very little trouble.

I'd like to write some 32- or 64-bit code in C and compile it, and call that code from the bootloader... basically a bootloader that, for example, sets the computer up to run some simple numerical simulation. I'll start by listing primes, for example, and then maybe some input/output from the user to maybe compute a Fourier transform. I don't know.

I haven't found *any* information on how to do this, but I can already foresee some problems before I even begin.

First of all, compiling a C program compiles it into one of several different files, depending on the *target*. For Windows, it's a PE file. For Linux, it's a .out file. These files are both quite different. In my instance, the target isn't Windows or Linux, it's just whatever I have written in the bootloader.

Secondly, where would the actual code reside? The bootloader is exactly 512 bytes, but the program I write in C will certainly compile to something much larger. It will need to sit on my (virtual) hard disk, probably in some sort of file system (which I haven't even defined!) and I will need to load the information from this file into memory before I can even think about executing it. But from my understanding, all this is many, many orders of magnitude more complex than a 12-line "Hello World" bootloader.

So my question is: How do I call a large 32- or 64-bit program (written in C/C++) from my 16-bit bootloader.

Comment: I would suggest looking at http://wiki.osdev.org . You can use BIOS to [load more data from disk](http://wiki.osdev.org/ATA_in_x86_RealMode_(BIOS)), then you need to get into [protected mode](http://wiki.osdev.org/Protected_Mode), or [long mode](http://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64) for 64-bit. THen you can parse an executable file, or just create a flat binary (gcc/ld can do this) that you can jump directly into.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is a huge topic.**

You should probably start by learning to enter and know [protected mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_mode).